# Database error. Wordpress. MySQL have shut down at 10:00 am

Tags: boot, mysql, database, wordpress

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my MySQL?

Ubuntu 14.04.

I can't understand what's going on..

```
140912 10:00:55 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140912 10:00:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140912 10:00:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140912 10:00:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140912 10:00:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140912 10:00:55 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140912 10:00:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140912 10:00:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140912 10:00:55 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140912 10:00:55  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140912 10:00:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140912 10:00:56 InnoDB: 5.5.37 started; log sequence number 4099203
140912 10:00:56 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140912 10:00:56 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140912 10:00:56 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140912 10:00:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140912 10:00:56 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
140912 10:00:57 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglcommentmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:57 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglcommentmeta'
140912 10:00:57 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglcomments' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:57 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglcomments'
140912 10:00:57 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbngloptions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:57 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbngloptions'
140912 10:00:57 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglpostmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:57 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglpostmeta'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglposts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglposts'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglterm_relationships' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglterm_relationships'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglterm_taxonomy' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglterm_taxonomy'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglusermeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglusermeta'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglusers' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglusers'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglwoocommerce_order_itemmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglwoocommerce_order_itemmeta'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglwoocommerce_order_items' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglwoocommerce_order_items'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglyith_wcwl' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './feba/flbnglyith_wcwl'
140912 10:00:58 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './phpmyadmin/pma_recent' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
140912 10:00:58 [Warning] Checking table:   './phpmyadmin/pma_recent'
140912 10:02:48 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

140912 10:02:48 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140912 10:02:49  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140912 10:02:49  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 4101802
140912 10:02:49 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140912 10:03:14 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140912 10:03:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140912 10:03:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140912 10:03:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140912 10:03:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140912 10:03:14 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140912 10:03:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140912 10:03:14 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140912 10:03:14 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140912 10:03:14  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140912 10:03:15 InnoDB: 5.5.37 started; log sequence number 4101802
140912 10:03:15 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140912 10:03:15 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140912 10:03:15 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140912 10:03:15 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140912 10:03:15 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

> [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './feba/flbnglcommentmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

... means you have problems with your tables.

Easy fix:

```
mysql -u{user} -p
```

And on the MySQL prompt do ...

```
>use {database};
>repair table {table};
```

for every table marked as crashed. Every repair will end with a report similar to:

```
+------------------+--------+----------+------------------------------------+
| Table            | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                           |
+------------------+--------+----------+------------------------------------+
| {db}.{table}     | repair | warning  | Number of rows changed from x to y |
| {db}.{mytable}   | repair | status   | OK                                 |
+------------------+--------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: To be honest, I can't access to mysql (and phpmyadmin), 1045 error..

Comment: Does It could be not only table problems?

Comment: @fzu can you access with mysql_safe from root?